# Unexpected result from momentjs diff when the compared dates are close

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When today's and tomorrow's date (April 17 and 18) are compared with the current moment (it's April 17 right now, for me) using the momentjs diff function, the number of days calculated are both 0.

Why is this, and what's a way to get a more sensible result?

```
function daysRemaining(eventdate) {
    var eventdatemoment = moment(eventdate);
    var todaysdate = moment();
    return eventdatemoment.diff(todaysdate, 'days');
}
console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-16'));
console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-17'));
console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-18'));
console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-19'));
```

Gives the result:

```
-1
0
0
1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ue110atu/1/

Comment: I see 0, 0, 1, 2. Where are you located? Makes sense. Today is less than a day away (obviously), and midnight tomorrow is less than twenty-four hours away.

Comment: Not sure if its related to your issue but just note that [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) returns a rounded down number since Moment.js 2.0.0. If you want a float, pass it `true` as a third parameter.

Comment: @ChristianHain I do want a whole number, however I want 1 as the result until 11:59pm the night before the event. Perhaps if I set the event date to have the time 11:59pm then? I don't think location should matter, but I'm in NZ with timezone GMT+12

Comment: No, it shouldn't, but that explains your `-1`. Are you saying you want `1, 2, 3, 4`, or `0, 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: @ChristianHain Sorry about the confusion, I've edited the current date into the question to make it clearer for anyone else reading it. With the dates I provided in my code, I wanted the results -1,0,1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function daysRemaining(eventdate) {
  var eventdatemoment = moment(eventdate);

  // Remove hours, minutes, seconds, etc. from today's date.
  var todaysdate = moment().startOf('day');

  return eventdatemoment.diff(todaysdate, 'days');
}

console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-16'));
console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-17'));
console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-18'));
console.log(daysRemaining('2015-04-19'));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [MomentJS Docs on `.diff()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/):

> By default, `moment#diff` will return number rounded down. If you want the floating point number, pass `true` as the third argument. Before 2.0.0, `moment#diff` returned rounded number, not a rounded *down* number.

Because you are running this code after midnight on 17 April 2015, the number of whole days rounded down between "now" and *midnight of 18 April 2015* is `0`.

I can see two options for getting a more "sensible" answer:

1. Pass `true` for the third parameter of `.diff()` to get a floating point number, without the rounding. You can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ue110atu/2/).
2. When setting the value of `todaysdate` in your function, use `moment().startOf('day')` to get the date for midnight today, which will correctly have a whole number of days difference to tomorrow of `1`.

Comment: Did you mean after midday, rather than after midnight?

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I used .startOf('day') as suggested by you and the other answer.

Comment: No, I definitely meant midnight, which is 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds and 0 milliseconds after the start of the day. :-) If you're only concerned with whole days, always strip off the hours, mins, secs and ms of all your `moment` dates by using `.startOf('day')`, it will lead to less bugs like the one you experienced.